# Deselect a selected object in Fabric.js

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I have multiple type objects on my canvas.
I can do scaling, rotation, etc. everything on a particular object.

But when I select a particular object, I want to change its `stroke` color.

```
canvas.observe('mouse:down', function(e) {

    activeInstance = canvas.getActiveObject();
    activeGroupInstance = canvas.getActiveGroup();
    if (activeInstance!=null){        
        activeInstance.set("stroke","#FF0000");
    }
}
```

The code works well. But the issue is that the `stroke` color or any other valid `property` doesn't reflect directly which means I have to deselect a currently selected object to see the change in its properties. So my question is what's going wrong? If this is the usual behavior that we have to deselect/click the selected object, then, how to deselect the selected object using code i.e without using mouse clicks simply using a code-snippet.

Comment: You just need to call `canvas.renderAll()` for changes to take effect

Comment: Ah! forget the basic requirement to render. Anyways, Thanks @kangax for the help!

Comment: @kangax: Can you suggest me some short and useful apps/demos ideas so that I can submit them in ChallengePost.

Comment: heh... maybe something with <video> element? or interesting animation of some sort (we don't have color animation, for example).

Comment: maybe something physics-aware, using box2d?

Comment: Yeah, Right. Thanks! I'll work on them.

Answer (score 2):

We can use below mentioned solutions.

To discard all active groups you can use below function.Discards currently active group and fire events If the function is called by fabric as a consequence of a mouse event, the event is passed as a parmater and sent to the fire function for the custom events. When used as a method the e param does not have any application.

```
canvas.discardActiveGroup();
```

To discard sigle object you can use like this. Discards currently active object and fire events. If the function is called by fabric as a consequence of a mouse event, the event is passed as a parmater and sent to the fire function for the custom events. When used as a method the e param does not have any application.

```
canvas.discardActiveObject();
```

And i the last finally renders both the top canvas and the secondary container canvas like this.

```
canvas.renderAll();
```